# Ejbca ant runinstall fails

Tags: java, wildfly, ejbca

I am working with :

```
ejbca_ce_6.3.1.1
wildfly10
java jdk8 update 121
MariaDb 10.1.21
ant 1.10
```

I was following the instructions on this page https://www.ejbca.org/docs/installation.html

I could not pass the steps:
ant runinstall
it throws the following error:

```
ejbca:install:

ejbca:initCA:
     [echo] Initializing CA with 'ManagementCA' 'CN=ManagementCA,O=EJBCA Sample,C=SE' 'soft' <ca.tokenpassword hidden> '2048' 'RSA' '3650' 'null' 'SHA256WithRSA'
  -superadmincn 'SuperAdmin'...
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.command.CliCommandPlugin: Provider org.ejbca.ui.cli.ke
ybind.InternalKeyBindingCreateCommand could not be instantiated
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.<init>(CommandLibrary.java:53)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.<clinit>(CommandLibrary.java:38)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.EjbcaEjbCli.main(EjbcaEjbCli.java:29)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:ejbca, moduleName:cesecore-ejb, distinctN
ame:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1dde4cb2
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
     [java]     at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
     [java]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAvailableTypesAndProperties(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.ejbca.ui.cli.keybind.InternalKeyBindingCreateCommand.<init>(InternalKeyBindingCreateCommand.java:69)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
     [java]     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
     [java]     ... 5 more

BUILD FAILED
C:\ejbca2\build.xml:70: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\ejbca2\bin\cli.xml:94: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\ejbca2\bin\cli.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\ejbca2\bin\cli.xml:186: Java returned: 1

Total time: 17 seconds
```

details of cli.xml: 112

```
<ejbca:cli-hideargs arg="ca init &quot;${ca.name}&quot; &quot;${ca.dn}&quot; ${ca.tokentype} ${ca.tokenpassword} ${ca.keyspec} ${ca.keytype} ${ca.validity} ${ca.policy} ${ca.signaturealgorithm} ${install.catoken.command} ${install.certprofile.command} -superadmincn &quot;${superadmin.cn}&quot;"/>
```

the step before that "ant clean deployear" shows the build has been successful.

I searched over the net without any success, please help

Answer (score 4):

I got the same stacktrace and the reason was that EJBCA (6.5.0.4) was not deployed to WildFly at the end of "ant clean deployear" (despite it showed success). So check the server.log when you run deployear.
For me the deploy failed because the default DB is not mysql but H2, and it tried to execute SQL statements that are valid for H2, but not for MariaDB (On MariaDB the  error was: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema). I had to define database.name=mysql in conf/database.properties and run "ant clean deployear" again and it solved the problem. Since you are using MariaDB, there is a good chance that you have the exact same error.

Comment: Thank you, mzsolt. yeah, the problem was as you said, deploy ear was not deployed properly. There was issues in connecting to mariadb. I had to fix mariadb problems first